# Queries to implement Navigation stack in simulation

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement navigation stack in simulation, but first I want to build the map and save to map server as it is requirement. To build the map, I have followed steps from this link :http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator/Tutorials/Create%20a%20map%20with%20gmapping

I am able to see the simulated map in rviz, how can I use this to load to the map server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260978/queries-to-implement-navigation-stack-in-simulation/) by [Ramesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30213/ramesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want to use the [map_saver node from the map_server package](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#map_saver). You can use this to store the map built with gmapping to disk (as a pgm image and a yaml file containing map metadata), and then later load that map using the `map_server`. Then you can do things like localize within the map using amcl.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ramesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30213/ramesh/) on 2017-05-03**:
I've built map and got two files one is .pgm and other in .yaml, Now how can load that map using map_server?
I am using this command, rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml and getting response :

[ INFO] [1493855683.820361988]: Read a 775 X 746 map @ 0.020 m/cell

how can I use this for amcl?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-04**:
[amcl calls the `static_map` service](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Services_Called) offered by the `map_server` to get a copy of the map.